Is there a way to compare two treatments with no shared outcome measures?
For context, I am performing a comparative effectiveness research study on Drug A, Drug B and Drug C. I want to identify the drug with highest efficacy, out of the three drugs.
Let's say that from three separate clinical trial results, I have reached to the conclusion that:

Drug A > Drug B (i.e. Drug A is more effective than Drug B)
Drug C > Drug B

Now, I have to compare Drug A and Drug C. However, I cannot find any shared primary/secondary outcome measures from the trials I am looking at, therefore I cannot make a indirect comparison.
My question: Is there a way that I can approach the comparison of Drug A and Drug C, given that they do not share any common outcome measures? I do not have advanced statistical knowledge, so my only shot to attempt this comparison through a simple indirect comparison, therefore I am aiming to make an approximation only.

Even comparisons with the same outcomes across studies are fraught: the groups studied are not the same, even if inclusion criteria are similar.

Combining results from different clinical trials is called meta analysis. You say "I do not have advanced statistical knowledge" and yet you're attempting to do what is arguably the most difficult type of statistical analysis.

I'm glad you got a comment on this. I've been trying to come up with any criteria for "effective" that doesn't need to be followed with "for..." and I can't. Even if a drug (A) were 100% effective at .1 mg/kg for the treatment of (condition X) while another drug (B) was 100% effective at .15 mg/kg for (condition Y), what would that even mean? If drug A treated runny noses and drug B treated psoriatic arthritis, should a drug company pursue development and marketing of drug A over drug B? The reason for the drug needs to be considered.
